# jQuery: fire call on fadeIn function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I'm currently using the `ImageZoom` plugin ([view here](http://codecanyon.net/item/imagezoom-responsive-jquery-image-zoom-plugin/4805256)), the plugin is great and works a charm. But for a site I'm working on the images (that you need to zoom into) are being appended to their container via `$("CONTAINER_CLASS_HERE").html('...etc`, thus aren't present on load (this function needs to stay too), this means though that the `ImageZoom()` function isn't working, even when calling it inside the `fadeIn` function. 
jSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/y2tdaak2/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.single-letting-lightbox-image').ImageZoom();

    $("button").click(function () {
        var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
        $("#area").fadeIn();
        $(".single-letting-lightbox-image-wrap").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='single-letting-lightbox-image' />")
            .hide().imagesLoaded(function () {
            $(this).delay(500).fadeIn(500, function () {
                $(this).ImageZoom();
            });

        });
    });

});
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated, can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are a working solution :) http://jsfiddle.net/y2tdaak2/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {           

        $("button").click(function () {
            var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
            $("#area").fadeIn();
            $(".single-letting-lightbox-image-wrap").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='single-letting-lightbox-image' />")
                .hide().imagesLoaded(function () {
                $(this).delay(500).fadeIn(500, function () {
                    $('.single-letting-lightbox-image').ImageZoom();
                });

            });
        });

    });
```

You need to call ImageZoom after the image is loaded :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to callback the function?

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").fadeIn();
    $(".single-letting-lightbox-image-wrap").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='single-letting-lightbox-image' />")
        .hide().imagesLoaded(function () {
        $(this).delay(500).fadeIn(500, function () {
            $(this).ImageZoom();
        });
    });
// callback the function to make it work again since the way you do this is not yet loaded
$('.single-letting-lightbox-image').ImageZoom();

});
```